# Click event with .on is not firing over appended elements

Tags: append, jquery

My problem is, that even when I use .on, the click event over added div with class added does not triggers.
This is my script from page.

```
$(".added").on("click", function () { alert("halo") });

$("#nextAdress").on("click",function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#trainerRegistrationFields").append('<div class="added">adsa</div>');
}
```

Can you please help me so the click event will trigger also on the dynamically added element with class added?

Tahnk you in advance

Comment: Variations on this question are one of the most frequently asked questions about jquery on SO. I googled your question title and the top 5 responses are all stackoverflow questions with the correct answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use event delegation syntax of [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamically added element.

```
$("#trainerRegistrationFields").on("click",".added", function (){ 
    alert("halo") ;
});
```

In your code you are binding the handler only to the element that existed in DOM during the time of event binding. You can also do this way:

or add the handler here while you append the item.

```
   function handleClick(){
      alert("halo");
   }

   $(".added").on("click", handleClick); //for the already existing elements

   $("#nextAdress").on("click",function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $("#trainerRegistrationFields").append($('<div class="added">adsa</div>').on('click', handleClick));
   }
```

Comment: curious why someone downvoted this. This is the correct answer.

Comment: Downvoter care to explain...

Comment: take back your +2, at least I never do revenges.